# What if I start a thread in infinite loop and update my database?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class SendMail implements Runnable { 
   Thread OracleBakThread;    
   Thread SleepThread = new  Thread(this);

   public static void main(String args[]){    
       SendMail objSendMail= new SendMail();    
       objSendMail.startInfiniteLoop();    
   }

   public void startInfiniteLoop() {   
        for(;;) {    
        SleepThread.sleep(1000);    
        OracleBakThread = new Thread(this);    
        OracleBakThread.start();}    
   }

   public void getBackupFun() {    
       dbConnectionFactory objdbConnectionFactory = new dbConnectionFactory();    
       Properties props = new Properties();    
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
       query = "check if database is false";    

       while (rs.next()) {    
                // If database is true, Send mail, Update database    
       }         
    }    

    public void run() {    
         int minute=0;    
         Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();    
         minute=calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);    

         if (minute==25) {    
             getBackupFun();      
         }   
    }                
}
```

And suppose my database is

```
id          b_status    
1           false
2           false    
3           false
```

So my question is, every time I create a new thread my run method will update a row. But as this thread creation is inside an infinite loop, how will my update work?

Will it keep on updating my database?

Or, first thread will update first row, second will update second?

Answer (score 0):

> But as this thread creation is inside an infinite loop, how will my
>   updation work?

This denpends on your update logic, for this the code inside `run()` is needed.

Also this probaply will cause Errors since the infinite loop will keep creating new Treads although the ones might not even be finished.

Comment: in my main java code , i am using a code like this: while(true){SleepThread.sleep(1000); OracleBakThread = new Thread(this); OracleBakThread.start();} and my program is working fine. I am here to understand how it works, whether a therad will update the whole database or multiple threads will do?

Comment: So you have to assume that the maximum amount of time every update needs is 1 second. This might work for you, but definetly is no good programming style, why do you even want to update every row in an own thread?

Comment: Actually I am sending a mail in that process, if database is false then send a mail and update my database. but logically speaking what will happen ? I dont know whether a therad will update one row, another will update another row. I am here to clearify that.

Comment: Then you should provide more code, because with the given one I can only tell you that you´re creating an infite amount oif threads (I can´t even tell what these threads are doing. I only can assume that the thread is calling the method `rum()`)

Comment: Have you ever worked with threading before? Looking yt your code I don´t think so... Your method `run()`is never going to be executed and `SleepThread.sleep(1000);` wont pasue the thread the loop is beeing executed in. Practice Threading in simpler examples first

Comment: This code is working fine. I am getting the desired output. I just wanna know its working.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel? Use Quartz library.
Refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465785/379779) in other thread.