# Dynamic Job Schedule Quartz

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to add/remove/modify Job which is scheduled in Quartz + Spring Boot dynamically (during run time) by the end user who are using my portal. Since schedule `start()` couldnt be accessed from outside I do not know is there any way. Basically I need to store all schedule information into Database and access them. Portal which Im building will be used by large number of users what would be the right solution to achieve this?

Otherwise can I use cron like below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 * * * *")
```

to scan jobs every 5 mns to achieve this.

Comment: You can find a complete example which might help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417393/full-spring-integration-with-quartz-to-implement-real-time-notification-e-mails/46418232#46418232).

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.

You just autowire the scheduler and whenever your user want to change task, you'd use `Scheduler#scheduleJob` and `Scheduler.deleteJob`with `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` instance (which represents the job).
To create cron job triggers use `Trigger` class.

Not runable excerpt from my code(EtlManager is proprietary class with method I want to run, etlTask is object containing persisted info on how often to run etc.):

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;
```

in method reacting on user adding new task:

```
        MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean jobDetail = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        EtlManager em = this.appContext.getBean(etlTask.getTask().getExeClass(), EtlManager.class);
        jobDetail.setTargetObject(em);
        jobDetail.setTargetMethod("run");
        jobDetail.setName(etlTask.getAppTaskCode());
        jobDetail.setGroup(this.appCode);
        jobDetail.setConcurrent(false);

        jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("CRON" + etlTask.getTiming().getId(), this.appCode)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(etlTask.getTiming().getCronExpression())
                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .startAt(etlTask.getTiming().getStartAfter()) //
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob((JobDetail) jobDetail.getObject(), trigger);
```

Also there is this quite similar QA here, not sure if 100% duplicate tough: [Java Example: Dynamic Job Scheduling with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669445/java-example-dynamic-job-scheduling-with-quartz)